# mixing templates with polymorphism

Tags: c++, templates, polymorphism

```
class A
{
    friend void foo();
    virtual void print_Var() const{};

};// does not contain variable Var;


template<class T>
class B : public A
{
    T Var;
public:
    B(T x):Var(x){}
    void print_Var() const override
    {
        std::cout<<Var<<std::endl;
    }
};

void foo()
{
    std::array<std::unique_ptr<A>, 3> Arr = {
            std::make_unique<B<int>>(100),
            std::make_unique<B<int>>(20),
            std::make_unique<B<std::string>>("Hello Stackoverflow")
    };
            std::shuffle(Arr.begin(), Arr.end(), std::mt19937(std::random_device()())); // 3rd parameter generated by Clang-Tidy

    for (auto &i: Arr)
    {
        i->print_Var(); // OK
      //  auto z = i->Var   // no member named Var in A
                            // obviously base class does not contain such variable

     //   if (i->Var==20) {/* do something*/}
     //   if (i->Var=="Hello Stackoverflow") {/* do something*/}

    }
}
```

Explanation:
I want to iterate over array of pointers to A, which is filled with pointers to classes derived from A, and depending on what type is variable Var, do some if( ) statement. 
Problem is that i cannot access Var, cause its not member of base class. However, it's possible to cout those values by, for example, overloaded function returning void. Could i write function in A class that returns templated type? like:

```
class A
{
    <class T> GetVar()
}
```

Besides, I feel like I'm dealing with this problem in totally improper way. Can i mix templates and inheritance like that? If not, how should it be designed?

Comment: You can use [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) to make a getter in the base class.

Comment: @NathanOliver you cannot have a heterogenous collection of CRTP base class.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot Right.  I new I was missing something.

Comment: https://cdn.fbsbx.com/v/t59.2708-21/50870465_375494809696528_7846460037777063936_n.pdf/Game-Server-Developer-assignment.pdf?_nc_cat=109&_nc_ht=cdn.fbsbx.com&oh=9817970db7a4e4cd33d9d470eacc8a73&oe=5C6880D0&dl=1                                   This is problem i want to solve, I want to iterate through 12 boxes and if i meet "Game Over" box, I want to exit function. But probably Im doing this completely wrongly.

Comment: Is this really a template issue, or a design issue?  You would have the same situation if no templates were used.

Comment: The question is why at that point in the code do you need to drill down to the `B` class?  The code is built to process `A` types, and trying to do `B` work explicitly in that section of the code seems like a design flaw.

Comment: This question was part of my first project in cpp and generally first in objective language. Could you(or somebody) check if the task was done properly with objective paradigm and feedback me?  If you agree, I'll post it on githuub.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a few choices. I'll explain my preferred solution first.

#### 1. Use dynamic dispatch

If you have an array of a base class type, why do you even want to do stuff with `Var`? That variable is specific to the child class. If you have a `A` somewhere, you shouldn't even care what `B` has or hasn't at that place.

Operations on the typed variable should be encapsulated in virtual function in the base class. If you want to do condition and stuff, maybe you could encapsulate that condition into a virtual function that returns a boolean.

#### 2a. Drop the base class and use variant

Sometimes, you know in advance the amount of types that will go into that list. Using a variant and drop the base class is a good solution that may apply to your case.

Let's say you only have `int`, `double` and `std::string`:

```
using poly = std::variant<B<int>, B<double>, B<std::string>>;

std::array<poly, 3> arr;

arr[0] = B<int>{};
arr[1] = B<double>{};
arr[2] = B<std::string>{};
// arr[2] = B<widget>{}; // error, not in the variant type

std::visit(
    [](auto& b) {
        using T = std::decay_t<decltype(b)>;
        if constexpr (std::is_same_v<B<int>, T>) {
            b.Var = 2; // yay!
        }
    },
    arr[0]
);
```

#### 2b. Drop the base class and use generic functions

Drop the base class entirely, and template your functions that do operation on them. You can move all your function into an interface or many `std::function`. Operate on that instead of the function directly.

Here's an example of what I meant:

```
template<typename T>
void useA(T const& a) {
    a.Var = 34; // Yay, direct access!
}

struct B {
    std::function<void()> useA;
};

void createBWithInt() {
    A<int> a;
    B b;

    b.useA = [a]{
        useA(a);
    };
};
```

This is fine for cases where you only have few operations. But it can quickly lead to code bloat if you have a lot of operations or if you have many types of `std::function`.

#### 3. Use a visitor

You could create a visitor that dispatch to the right type.

This solution would be much close to what you except, but is quite combersome and can break easily when adding cases.

Something like this:

```
struct B_Details {
protected:
    struct Visitor {
        virtual accept(int) = 0;
        virtual void accept(double) = 0;
        virtual void accept(std::string) = 0;
        virtual void accept(some_type) = 0;
    };

    template<typename T>
    struct VisitorImpl : T, Visitor {
        void accept(int value) override {
            T::operator()(value);
        }

        void accept(double) override {
            T::operator()(value);
        }

        void accept(std::string) override {
            T::operator()(value);
        }

        void accept(some_type) override {
            T::operator()(value);
        }
    };
};

template<typename T>
struct B : private B_Details {
    template<typename F>
    void visit(F f) {
        dispatch_visitor(VisitorImpl<F>{f});
    }

private:
    virtual void dispatch_visitor(Visitor const&) = 0;
};

// later

B* b = ...;

b->visit([](auto const& Var) {
    // Var is the right type here
});
```

Then of course, you have to implement the `dispatch_visitor` for each child class.

#### 4. Use `std::any`

This is litteraly returning the variable with type erasure. You cannot do any operation on it without casting it back:

```
class A {
    std::any GetVar()
};
```

I personnaly don't like this solution because it can break easily and is not generic at all. I would not even use polymorphism in that case.

Answer (score 1):

I think it will be the easiest way. Just move the comparison method to the interface and override it in derived classes. Add the following lines to yor example:

```
class A
{
   /*..................................................*/
   virtual bool comp(const int) const { return false; }
   virtual bool comp(const std::string) const { return false; }
   virtual bool comp(const double) const { return false; }  
};

template<class T>
class B : public A
{
   /*..................................................*/
   virtual bool comp(const T othr) const override { return othr == Var; }
};

void foo()
{
      /*..................................................*/
      if (i->comp(20))
      {
         /* do something*/
      }

      if (i->comp("Hello Stackoverflow"))
      {
         /* do something*/
      }
      /*..................................................*/
}
```