# C++ Templates for polymorphism? "Use of class template requires template arguments"

Tags: java, c++, templates, generics, polymorphism

I'm new to C++ and am trying to figure out how to use templates to build a hierarchy of classes of specific types for polymorphism. I know how to do this in Java pretty easily with generics.  I'm sure this has been asked before, but I simply don't know what terms to use to search for what I want in C++.

I want to be able to use a base class that I've created using a combination of objects made up of the very specified classes defined below as `Derived_1` and `Derived_2`, each of which extend from a class named `Base`. However, I get a compiler error saying I need to declare the type? What syntax do I use to indicate that this `z` vector, used in the implementation, could be made up of any combination of classes that extend from `Base`?

Here is what I have so far, which I think is mostly correct when it comes to declaring the base class and the classes that extend that base class:

### base_types.h

```cpp
template <typename T>
class Base {
public:
    Base<T>(size_t a, T b) :
            m_a(a),
            m_b(b) {
    }

    T getB() const;

    size_t m_a;
    T m_b;
};

// specific kind of Base that uses bool
class Derived_1 : public Base<bool> {
    Derived_1(uint32_t a);     // second parameter is unused, is assumed to be "true"
    bool getB();
};


// specific kind of Base that uses size_t
class Derived_2 : public Base<size_t> {
    Derived_2(uint32_t a, size_t b);
    size_t getB();
};
```

#### base_types.cpp

```cpp
Derived_1::Derived_1(uint32_t a) : Base(a, true) { }      // second parameter is unused, is assumed to be "true"

bool Derived_1::getB() { return m_b; }


Derived_2::Derived_2(uint32_t a, size_t b) : Base(a, b) { }

bool Derived_2::getB() { return m_b; }
```

#### impl_types.h

```cpp
#include "base_types.h"
#include <vector>

class Foo {
public:
    Foo(
        size_t y,
        const std::vector<Base>& z);      // Error: Use of class template 'Base' requires template arguments
};
```

#### impl_types.cpp

```cpp
class Foo {
public:
    Foo(
        size_t y,
        const std::vector<Base>& z) :      // Error: Use of class template 'Base' requires template arguments
            m_y{y},
            m_z{z};
};
```

For reference, here's the Java implementation of what I want to do:

```java
// Base.java
class Base<T> {
    int m_a;
    T m_b;

    Base(int a, T b) {
        m_a = a;
        m_b = b;
    }

    T getB() {
        return m_b;
    }
}
```

```java
// Derived_1.java
class Derived_1 extends Base<Boolean> {
    Derived_1(int a, Boolean a) {
        super(a, b);
    }

    Boolean getB() {
        return m_b;
    }
}
```

```java
// Derived_2.java
class Derived_2 extends Base<String> {
    Derived_2(int a, String b) {
        super(a, b);
    }

    String getB() {
        return m_b;
    }
}
```

```java
// Main.java
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Base> baseList = new ArrayList<>();
        baseList.add(new Derived_1(1, true));
        baseList.add(new Derived_2(2, "foo"));

        for(Base o : baseList) {
            System.out.println(o.getB());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that Javas generics are really something very different from templates. While generics use some sort of type erasure, templates is all at compile time. During runtime there are not templates, one consequence is that eg you cannot have the equivalent of javas `new ArrayList<>()` unless you implement some sort of type erasure similar to what comes with javas generics

Comment: please include the error message in the question

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 it's in the title and in the question: "Error: Use of class template '...' requires template arguments"

Comment: ah ok its in the comments. I am used to ignore comments ;). The error is just what it says. In `std::vector<T>` the `T` must be a type, but `Base` is just a template

Comment: what do you actually want to achieve again? Can you write a C++ main with an example of how you want to use it? I have difficulties to see from the java example what you want to do in c++, because as I said, `new ArrayList<>();` is using generics and templates arent generics. If you want an array that can hold instances of different classes that all inherit from a common base, there is a solution, but it doesnt require you to write a template

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 I'm fine with not using templates if that isn't the way to do this. I do just want to hold an vector of objects of different classes that inherit from a common base class, but *with a method that is shared among those classes that returns a different type, depending on that particular class*

Answer (score 3):

You can't have `std::vector<Base>` since `Base` is template. You should have `std::vector<Base<bool>>`, `std::vector<Base<size_t>>`  or the like. `Base<bool>` and `Base<size_t>` are different types that have nothing else common than being made using same template `Base`.

May be what you want is `std::vector<std::variant<Base<bool>,Base<size_t>>>` but
it is hard to tell from your code. The `std::variant` is for having variables that can have values of different types (with possibly nothing in common).

You can't put objects of derived classes into vector of base class so you should use `std::vector<std::variant<Derived1,Derived2>>` when you want these to be by value in same vector. Dynamically polymorphic objects have to have exactly same base class and even then you need to put these into containers by reference to base not by value.

Comment: I need something that can be an unknown type. I don't know ahead of time what kind of `Base` this vector will hold, like: `std::vector<Base<?>>`

Comment: @KyleFalconer vector stores it's objects contiguously, os 1) all objects must be the same (of the same size) 2) they should be know statically.  `std::variant` provides means to do that for the static polymorphism. In Java, there is simply no values, only pointers, so the closest analog would be just `std::vector<Base*>`, with the real Base class and virtual methods. I.e. you can get the same result, but not with templates, since `Base<int>` and `Base<bool>` are different "unrelated" types.

Answer (score 3):

In java this works because a `ArrayList<Widget>` is basically `ArrayList<Object>`. This comes with some advantages, but also with disadvantage.

In C++, there are templates instead of generics. With similar goal in mind, they are very different in terms of implementation and implication.

As their name states: they are templates. A class template is not a class. It's some kind of entity that only exist in compile time. Only when a template is instantiated it become something concrete.

ELI5 on the process of instanciating a template: `std::vector` is the template. `std::vector<int>` is an instanciation of the template. The template is instanciated by filling the holes of the code, denoted by the template argument:

```
template<typename T>
auto value() -> T { return T{}; }

int main() {
    return value<int>() + value<short>();
}
```

Two functions are instantiated and kinda look like that:

```
template<> //   v---- T has been replaced!
auto value() -> int { return int{}; }

template<> // Another instantiation
auto value() -> short { return short{}; }
```

Of course, the compiler don't replace it textually, but rather use an AST to resolve the actual types.

This was to show you that the template don't really exist after the process. Only the instantiations are concrete. And there are multiple instantiations.

Just as the function template above, when a template class is instantiated, a whole new type is created. The types created by the instantiations are completely unrelated. They simply are distinct types, just as template functions produce distinct instantiations.

---

So... how do you do the polymorphism if you have many distinct, unrelated classes?

You add an interface!

```
struct Interface {
    // TODO: put useful function there
};

template<typename T>
struct Base : Interface {
    virtual auto getB() const -> T;
};

struct Impl1 : Base<bool> {
    auto getB() const -> T override;
};
```

---

If on the contrary, your intent was to do somthing like this:

```
Base b = ...;

// pseudocode
if (typeid(b->getB()) == bool)
{
    bool b = dynamic_cast<bool>(b->getB());
}
else if (typeid(b->getB()) == std::size_t)
{
    std::size_t b = dynamic_cast<std::size_t>(b->getB());
}
```

Then, a variant, like the other answers stated, are the solution. If you list the possible types like this, then you know the list of possible type of `Base` in advance. So a `std::variant` is what you want.

To make variant easier to use, you can always alias the type:

```
using VBase = std::variant<Base<bool>, Base<std::size_t>, ...>
```

If you need other means to do polymorphism with templates, then see my older anwser on the subject: [mixing templates with polymorphism](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54712268/2104697)

Answer (score 2):

If you make a non-templated empty base class, a template that inherits from it, then the specializations, you can store base pointers in a vector or any other structure.
If you want to use the stored objects, you have to cast them back to the actual type explicitly (this has to be done in Java too, if I'm correct).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_software_engineering

Answer (score 2):

**Error: Use of class template `Base` requires template arguments**

You get the error because `Base` is not a type, but just a template. Don't confuse c++ tempaltes with java generics, they are really very different concepts. You cannot have a vector of templates, because templates are just templates. You need to instantiate them to get a type. You can for example have a `std::vector<Base<bool>>`.

Another problem in your code is that `Base` should have a virtual destructor. Otherwise you are in danger of getting memory leaks. Methods have to be declared as `virtual` to enable dynamic dispatch.

That being said...

**What you actually want to do:**

> I do just want to hold an vector of objects of different classes that
>   inherit from a common base class, [...]

You do not need templates for that. That would be as simple as:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <utility>
struct base { 
    virtual void some_method(){ std::cout << "base\n";}
    virtual ~base(){}
};
struct foo : base {
    virtual void some_method() override { std::cout << "foo\n";}
};
struct bar : base {
    virtual void some_method() override { std::cout << "bar\n";}
};


int main() {
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<base>> v;
    v.emplace_back(new foo());
    v.emplace_back(new bar());

    for (auto& e : v) e->some_method();
    return 0;
}
```

Polymorphism works with pointers or references. As it isnt that straight-forward to store references in containers, I used pointers. And I use a smart pointer, because I dont want to mess around with manual memory managment.

**So far so good...**

> [...] but with a method that is shared among those classes that returns a
>   different type, depending on that particular class

This however, is not that easy. First of all, note that the same method cannot have different return types. Just as an example, if you have

```
struct example_base { 
    virtual int foo() { return 1;} 
};
struct example_derived {
    virtual double foo() override { return 1.4; }
};
```

then `example_derived::foo` does **not** override `example_base::foo` ! Thanks to `override` the compiler will tell you that via an error message along the line of

```
prog.cc:20:24: error: 'foo' marked 'override' but does not override any member functions
        virtual double foo() override { return 1.4; }
                       ^
```

Depending on what you actually want to achieve (why do you need the derived to "share a common method" with different return type?) there are different ways to solve that. I will show you one way.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <utility>

struct return_type_base { 
    virtual void print() {}
    virtual ~return_type_base() {}
};

struct bool_return_type : return_type_base {
    bool value = true;
    virtual void print() { std::cout << value << "\n"; }
};
struct int_return_type : return_type_base {
    int value = 3;
    virtual void print() { std::cout << value << "\n"; }
};

using return_type_ptr = std::shared_ptr<return_type_base>;

struct base { 
    virtual return_type_ptr some_method() = 0;
    virtual ~base(){}
};
struct foo : base {
    virtual return_type_ptr some_method() override { 
        return return_type_ptr(new bool_return_type());
    }
};
struct bar : base {
    virtual std::shared_ptr<return_type_base> some_method() override { 
        return return_type_ptr(new int_return_type());
    }
};


int main() {
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<base>> v;
    v.emplace_back(new foo());
    v.emplace_back(new bar());

    for (auto& e : v) e->some_method()->print();
    return 0;
}
```

It is basically the exactly same approach as above. To treat different types polymorphically we declare a common base class and work on shared pointers of that base class. As mentioned before this is just one possible approach. Please take it with a grain of salt, it is just meant to give you a starting point. The major drawbacks are: It is intrusive (you have to write a class for each type you want to return) and it uses virtual functions (ie runtime overhead). There are better ways but then the details matter on what you actually want to do with those different return types. For further reading I suggest you to search for "type erasure".

**TL;DR**

Templates are a pure compile-time concept. If you want to treat different types equally at runtime you need some form of runtime type-erasure. The techniques available for that are rather different in Java and C++. Runtime polymorphism via virtual functions works in both and is maybe the most comprehensible one, especially when you are coming from Java. You should also take a look at what the standard library has to offer ([`std::any`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any), [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant)).